# AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column '_sa_instance_state' Flask-sqlAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

im developing a new project, im building a small CRM web app using Flask. Im very new using this technology. Im getting this error: AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column '_sa_instance_state' when i try to create a new quote for a client.

Model: I have three tables: Clientes, Solicitud and Cotizacion (Quotes). I have the issue on crearcotizacion view, but i dont know how resolve this? all help is very appreciated.

```
class Clientes(db.Model):
  
    __tablename__ = "clientes"


    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombres = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    apellidos = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    correo = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    empresa = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    celular = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    mensaje = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    checkbox = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    cotizaciones = db.relationship('Cotizacion', backref='clientes_cotizan', lazy=True)
    solicitudes = db.relationship('Solicitud', backref='sol_client', lazy=True)

    
    

    def __init__(self, nombres, apellidos, correo, empresa, celular, mensaje, checkbox, sol_client):
        
        self.nombres = nombres
        self.apellidos = apellidos
        self.correo = correo
        self.empresa = empresa
        self.celular = celular
        self.mensaje = mensaje
        self.checkbox = checkbox
        self.sol_client = sol_client
        
        
    

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Clientes %r>' % self.id


class Solicitud(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "solicitud"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    
    servicio_campo = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    asesore = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)

     # LLAVE FORANEA
    solicitud_cliente = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("clientes.id"), nullable=True)
    solicitudes_cliente = db.relationship('Cotizacion', backref='clientes_solicitan', lazy=True)

    

    def __init__(self, servicio_campo, asesore, sol_client):
       
        self.servicio_campo = servicio_campo
        self.asesore = asesore
        self.sol_client = sol_client
       



class Cotizacion(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "cotizacion"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   
    numero_horas = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    
    descuento = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    # LLAVE FORANEA
    cliente_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("clientes.id"), nullable=True)
    solicitud_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("solicitud.id"), nullable=True)
    

    def __init__(self, numero_horas, descuento, clientes_cotizan, clientes_solicitan):
       
        self.numero_horas = numero_horas
        self.descuento = descuento
        self.clientes_cotizan = clientes_cotizan
        self.clientes_solicitan = clientes_solicitan
      
       

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Cotizacion %r>' % self.id
```

My view

```
@app.route('/cotizaciones/crear/<int:id>', methods=("GET", "POST"))

@login_required

def crearcotizacion(id):
    
    
    datos_clientes = (db.session.query(Clientes.id, Clientes.nombres, Clientes.apellidos, Clientes.empresa, Clientes.correo, Solicitud.id, Solicitud.servicio_campo, Solicitud.asesore).join(Solicitud).filter_by(id=id).one())
    
    datos_solicitud = (db.session.query(Solicitud).filter_by(id=Solicitud.id).first())
    
    form = creacion_Cotizacion(request.form)

    if current_user.role == True:
        
        if request.method == 'POST':

            cotizan = Cotizacion(
           
            numero_horas=form.numero_horas.data,
            descuento=form.descuento.data,
            clientes_cotizan = datos_clientes,
            clientes_solicitan= datos_solicitud
            
            )
            
            db.session.add(cotizan)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('La cotización ha sido creado exitosamente', 'success')
            return render_template('crearcotizacion.html', form=form, id=id, datos_solicitud=datos_solicitud, datos_clientes=datos_clientes)
            
    else:
        abort(401)

    return render_template('crearcotizacion.html', nombres=current_user.nombres, correo=current_user.correo, role=current_user.role, id=id, form=form, datos_solicitud=datos_solicitud, datos_clientes=datos_clientes)
```

In this view, user can pick the requests for each client

```
    @app.route('/listarcotizacion')
    @login_required
    def listarcotizacion():
        if current_user.role == True:
            clientes= db.session.query(Solicitud.id, Solicitud.servicio_campo, Solicitud.asesore, Clientes.nombres, Clientes.apellidos, Clientes.correo, Clientes.empresa, Clientes.mensaje, Clientes.celular).join(Clientes).all()
            return render_template('listacotizacion.html', clientes=clientes, nombres=current_user.nombres, correo=current_user.correo)
```

Error message

```
AttributeError
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column '_sa_instance_state'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 277, in decorated_view
return current_app.ensure_sync(func)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/georgeboy/sanwise/app.py", line 905, in crearcotizacion
cotizan = Cotizacion(
File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 480, in _initialize_instance
manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
compat.raise_(
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
raise exception
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 477, in _initialize_instance
return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
File "/home/georgeboy/sanwise/app.py", line 159, in __init__
self.clientes_cotizan = clientes_cotizan
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 459, in __set__
self.impl.set(
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1268, in set
value = self.fire_replace_event(state, dict_, value, old, initiator)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1294, in fire_replace_event
value = fn(
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1729, in emit_backref_from_scalar_set_event
instance_state(child),
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2095, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 279, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/georgeboy/sanwise/app.py", line 905, in crearcotizacion
cotizan = Cotizacion(
File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 480, in _initialize_instance
manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
compat.raise_(
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
raise exception
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 477, in _initialize_instance
return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
File "/home/georgeboy/sanwise/app.py", line 159, in __init__
self.clientes_cotizan = clientes_cotizan
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 459, in __set__
self.impl.set(
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1268, in set
value = self.fire_replace_event(state, dict_, value, old, initiator)
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1294, in fire_replace_event
value = fn(
File "/home/georgeboy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1729, in emit_backref_from_scalar_set_event
instance_state(child),
AttributeError: Could not locate column in row for column '_sa_instance_state'
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick!, in this view crearcotizacion(id), i use this to create a new quotation for a client. Using this view i have Solicitud Table and Client Table to render this data (Clientes.nombres, Clientes.apellidos, Clientes.empresa, Solicitud.servicio_campo and Solicitud.asesore) to the user. When a new quote is created, I need to be able to identify this quote is related to which request and which customer

Comment: oh yeah sorry i forgot to put this part, issue updated with this info. In listarcotizacion view, the user can pick each client request. and in crearcotizacion view, the user can view the clients data and the request data to create a quotation. I need to know a quotation is linked to a request and belongs to a client.

Comment: Ok, from what I understand, why couldn't you simply do, `datos_clientes = (db.session.query(Clientes).filter_by(id=id).first())`?

Comment: Hi Patrick, when i use this datos_clientes =(db.session.query(Clientes).filter_by(id=id).first()), information about client not match because brings the info for the first client but not the client that match with the request made for that client.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite follow. The part `.filter_by(id=id)` ensures that the the client matches with the requested id. The `.first()` on the end ensures that a valid object is returned, and in the case of multiple objects having the same id, (which they wouldn't), it would return the first object. Basically, I just write `.first()` to get the first and only value that has a matching id. Maybe you could tell me a bit more what you mean by "request made for that client"?

Comment: ok great! many thanks for this comment helps me a lot. I will review this association between Request, Quotation and clients. Basically, i want to create request for a client thats part already works, and then in a view Crearcotizacion put all the requests created for that client, if i clicked i want to see all client information and additional fields in order to enter the value and duration for the service requested.

Comment: Oh, thanks! im learning a lot with you! Patrick this sol_client is a backref that i create to relation Request (Solicitud) table and Clients (Clientes) table. 

solicitudes = db.relationship('Solicitud', backref='sol_client', lazy=True)

Comment: Ok, I think I finally got it figured out. You are trying to create a 'Cotizacion', but you need the selected 'Clientes' and 'Solicitud' objects to create your 'Cotizacion'. Querying for the 'Solicitud' object is simple because you have the desired id. The problem is getting the 'Clientes' object with only the 'Solicitud's id. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes Patrick that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as utilizing the 'Solicitud's `sol_client` backref. Try this:

```
@app.route('/cotizaciones/crear/<int:id>', methods=("GET", "POST"))
@login_required
def crearcotizacion(id):
    
    datos_solicitud = (db.session.query(Solicitud).filter_by(id=Solicitud.id).first())
    datos_clientes = datos_solicitud.sol_client
    
    form = creacion_Cotizacion(request.form)

    if current_user.role == True:

        if request.method == 'POST':

            cotizan = Cotizacion(
           
            numero_horas=form.numero_horas.data,
            descuento=form.descuento.data,
            clientes_cotizan = datos_clientes,
            clientes_solicitan= datos_solicitud
            
            )
            
            db.session.add(cotizan)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('La cotización ha sido creado exitosamente', 'success')
            return render_template('crearcotizacion.html', form=form, id=id, datos_solicitud=datos_solicitud, datos_clientes=datos_clientes)
            
    else:
        abort(401)

    return render_template('crearcotizacion.html', nombres=current_user.nombres, correo=current_user.correo, role=current_user.role, id=id, form=form, datos_solicitud=datos_solicitud, datos_clientes=datos_clientes)
```

To explain this, we are getting the desired `Solicitud` object with a simple filtered query using the selected 'id'. We then use the backref `sol_client` of this 'Solicitud' object to get the parent client. This is much simpler than performing a separate query to get the 'Client' object from the 'Solicitud's id.

Comment: Yeah! ok, i get it, its more than simple, It works! I made only a little modification in this part:  datos_solicitud = (db.session.query(Solicitud).filter_by(id=id).first()). Many thanks Patrick! im learning a lot with your advices. thanks!

Comment: Thanks Patrick! answers accepted. Sorry, one question for you, i have another table call Servicio (Service) in this table i have the services that the company offers and its cost by hour. How i can have the cost value from a service that are in specific request (Solicitud). I need to put a foreign key from Solicitud table to Service Table?

Comment: Yes, I believe you have it right. I don't completely understand what you are trying to do, but I can say that whichever table is your 'parent' table (as in, it will have multiple tables under it) needs to have the `db.relationship` column, and your 'child' table (the one that is linked to its parent) has the ForeignKey column. I hope this helps you out, but if you need too much more information, it might be best to ask a new question.